# CakePHP trying to send a ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I'm trying to send a ajax requistion to a controller, that it should returns something, but isn't.
My element (View/Elements/list.ctp):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'showProducts')); ?>',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<p id="click">Click me!</p>
```

Controller products:

```
<?php
    class ProductsController extends AppController {
        public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
        public $components = array('RequestHandler');
        var $name = 'Products';

        function showProducts(){

            return 'This should to return in jQuery data';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cakePHP 2.x your controller needs to be in this way to return json data to the $.ajax request :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('JsBaseEngineHelper', 'View/Helper');

class AjaxtestsController extends AppController {

function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

public function returnsSomthing()
    {
        $layout = 'ajax'; // you need to have a no html page, only the data.
        $this->autoRender = false; // no need to render the page, just plain data.
        $data = array();
        $jquerycallback = $_POST["callback"];
        //do something and then put in $data those things you want to return.
        //$data will be transformed to JSON or what you configure on the dataType.

        echo JsBaseEngineHelper::object($data,array('prefix' => $jquerycallback.'({"totalResultsCount":'.count($data).',"ajt":','postfix' => '});'));
    }

}
```

**Improved Answer**

You can use your controller's methods to search data on the db: find(), but I move the search queries to the Model:

First: Add the marked lines at the model code

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility'); // <---
App::uses('JsBaseEngineHelper', 'View/Helper'); // <---
```

Second: Create a Model method that executes the search:

```
public function getdata(){
        $input = NULL; 
        $query = array();
        $sql = NULL;
        $data = array();
        $i = 0;

        $input = $_GET["name_startsWith"]; // <-- obtains the search parameter
        $input = Sanitize::clean($input); // <-- prepares the search parameter

        $sql = "select * from atable where condition like '".$input."%';";

        $query = $this->query($sql); // <-- the model execute the search

        if ($query){
            $c = count($query);
            for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){ // <-- iterate over the returned data
                $json['id'] = $query[$i][0]['id'];
                $json['column1'] = $query[$i][0]['column1'];
                $json['column2'] = $query[$i][0]['column2'];
                $data[] = $json; // <-- the data it's stored on an multiarray, to be converted to JSON
            }
        }
        $jquerycallback = $_GET["callback"];
        echo JsBaseEngineHelper::object($data,array('prefix' => $jquerycallback.'({"totalResultsCount":'.count($query).',"search":','postfix' => '});')); //<-- the data it´s returned as JSON
    }
```

Then: On the controller create a method to call the search

```
public function getdata()
    {
        $layout = 'ajax'; //<-- No LAYOUT VERY IMPORTANT!!!!!
        $this->autoRender = false;  // <-- NO RENDER THIS METHOD HAS NO VIEW VERY IMPORTANT!!!!!
        $this->Cliente->getclient(); // <-- Get the data
    }
```

You can call this method via ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/application/controller/getdata",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 10,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.search, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                value: item.id,
                                label: item.column1+" "+item.column2
                            }

                        }));

                    }
            });
```

Check this for more info:

- [CakePHP Controller:autorender](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render)
- [CakePHP JsonView](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-1.html#jsonview)

Comment: Nice man! So, if I wanna return data from a search, should I return what? and how jQuery would render this? assuming that I already have a requestAction at View that renders my data..

Comment: ok i'm trying to understand and apply.. ajax will return a json with data.. Currently I have a requestAction to fill data, how that json would replace this data? thanks

Comment: what you want to do? an autocomplete?

Comment: ok, you have to do something like this: do a query for the products, create an array with the info, then on the success event of the ajax iterate the data returned and using $("#product").html(st) where st it's a html formated string with the content of the div.

Comment: Look this, actually my div is being filled using requestAction, to use your way, should I keep requestAction for first time of loading the page? or should I call AJAX when page loads to put data in my div?

Comment: Another thing, this way you told me, I should have a Controller with a View, that will be called from AJAX, in this view he will return my HTML with data that came from controller, and my AJAX will push information from this view and render in my div? idk if I'm right, correct me.

Comment: 1) you can use requestAction or ajax to do the same thing. requestAction is used to retreive data from the model via it's controller's method, the data it's returned on an array based list and then used on an element to be placed anywhere on a view, the element it's returned as a HTML string, but elements need to be cached and if you use as "product placeholder" it's unpractical. The Ajax way it's more about "speed perception", the page it's loaded and then an ajax method "fills" the content.

Comment: 2) you call directly the action or method on the controller, no view is needed. The data it's received by the ajax request and mus be processed on the success event, and **YOU MUST HANDLE THE DATA**, iterate over the results, create a string containing the HTML code that must be "injected" on the "host page" via `$("#divid").html(htmlstring)`.

Comment: I've done the following: a View to display my table, AJAX in this view that calls a Controller with `$this->set` and in this Controller's View, my table is rendered, and in AJAX, he returns the content of this view to my div with `.html()`.. it worked, but.. is that right? thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Typo Quotes mismatch

Use double quotes to wrap

```
url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'showProducts')); ?>",     
     ^                                                                                         ^
```

---

Problem

```
url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'products',
                                          var ^ str^ var
```

`controller` and `products` are treated as variables not strings

Comment: updated: `url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'products'` gives error "SyntaxError: missing } after property list"

Comment: `url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'showProducts')); ?>",
    success: function(data){
           alert(data);
         }` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JulianoLima Try `url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('
+ controller + ' => ' + products + ', ' + action + ' => ' + showProducts + ')); ?>'`

Comment: didn't work.. now i'm trying with `url: '/cakephp/products/showProducts',` it should works, isn't? but doesn't returns anything, even gives an error.

Comment: Just worked! thanks buddy, my $('#click') was another id, hahahha sorry!

Comment: @JulianoLima great :)