# CakePHP dynamic search with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

currently I have a search that calls once a Controller Action with requestAction and returns a data array, then I use foreach to list in a table..
So, how could I implant a button that refreshs the table without leave the page?

thanks

Edited:
I have a element from a View called table.ctp, inside there is:
`$products = $this->requestAction('/products/getAll');`
then

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    echo $product['Product']['Name'];
}
```

/\ render all my products that came from /products/getAll.

Controller products, action getAll():

```
function getAll(){
    return $this->Product->getProducts();
}
```

Model (Product.php), the function `getProducts()` returns `$this->find('all')`

I want to have an input in table.ctp that when I click a button, he will refresh the table with AJAX..
I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '',  
                success: function(data){

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

but I have no idea how to proceed, which URL call, and this way is right..

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I answered that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911685/cakephp-trying-to-send-a-ajax-request), hope it fulfills your expectations.

Ask for more help... ;)

D.